# What is Windowsoft?

Tags: windows, floppy

I found an old floppy disc for Windows Forms Maker and on it it says the software requires "Microsoft® Windowsoft™ 3.1 and up." Was this just a typo, or is "Microsoft Windowsoft" a thing? It says it was a trademarked named, so that's what makes me more skeptical that it was a typo.

[image: The disc]

Comment: It says (C) 1994.  In 1994, Windows 3.1 was the latest American release of Microsoft Windows.  (Windows 95 wasn't released yet.)  At that time, Microsoft Windows was a common requirement.  (Lots of software did not require Windows, but some did.  Software commonly listed requirements, like CPU or memory or hard drive space.)  Microsoft Windows is, by far, the only sensible thing that this could be referring to.  I'm awarding Aganju with an upvote for a useful observation, and awaring Julie Pelletier with an upvote for providing an answer that is quite correct (and, therefore, useful).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zoom in, it says 'Microsoft Windows', then a symbol that looks like `<>`, then an `ft`TM. It's not an 'o'.

Comment: +1 for pointing it out!  Can you explain these symbols too?

Comment: No. sorry. I tried to search around, but aside from some info about Cosmi Corp. I did not find anything specific. They seem to make shovelware since 1982, not bad, 34 years on this market and still alive...

Comment: Oh wow, this is the answer right here. I didn't even notice that! I wonder what <>ft™ means, then?